# Laravel CSS and JS in public folder showing 404 error

Tags: javascript, php, css, laravel

I have my CSS and JS in the public folder and when I load my site it is showing the files as 404 error resource not found. How can I resolve?
I have the below index file in my root folder

`require __DIR__.'/bootstrap/autoload.php';`

`$app = require_once __DIR__.'/bootstrap/app.php';`

I then have my layouts file calling the css/js files like for example...

```
href="{{ asset('plugins/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css') }}"
src="{{ asset('plugins/bootstrap-modal/js/bootstrap-modal.js') }}"
```

What else do I need to change?  i dont wish to add public in the path for the resources. How else can I do this?

Server config file is as below

```
if ($uri !== '/' && file_exists(__DIR__.'/public'.$uri)) {
return false;
}
require_once __DIR__.'/public/index.php';
```

Comment: which web server do you use? Often its just a configuration on your web server (nginx/apache etc) config file. Also post your web server's config file to get better assistance.

Comment: I am using Apache.

Answer (score 0):

You could include bootstrap from this website: https://cdnjs.com/libraries/twitter-bootstrap/
There is also performance gain using this method.